# Store detail data in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a Parent/Child form. For example, the parent table may have the following field

1. Number of projects completed
2. Have you ever worked with our company? (Yes/No radio button)

If the second option have 'Yes' value, then I need to fill the details form.
For example: "The project name done with our company, copy of contract to be uploaded etc."

I have the following logic,
The deatils form may have a ADD button to add deatils records. I think I can store the details data in JavaScript arrays? Can I store the

```
<input type="file" name="file_to_upload" />
```

in arrays ?

Then on the submit button, send the parent and child deatils to the database.
Is there any other method to accomplish the task ?
Please see the screen snap
[image]

**I can only add one detail records at a time. My question is, where should I temporarily store the deatil list ?**

Comment: Why do you need to store anything with javascript? Surely it'll all be in the `$_GET` array after you submit the form?

Comment: @ChrisW Actually I need to store a data table. Suppose the fields are Name, Age, Sex, Image.
There may be number of records like this. So at the left, I place input text boxes one by one. In the left, I need to store the deatails in a table where I will use <a> for Name. All othere fields may be hidden. To edit the record, I will click the Name <a>, so the record will get populated in input controls.

Comment: Can you put an example of your html on jsfiddle? It'll help visualise exactly what you want

Comment: @ChrisW Please see the attached image.

Comment: File uploads are only carried out when the server-side script is run.  If 'Add new' and/or 'Save & continue' are just firing JavaScript events, you'll have to make sure that the field names / IDs they create are unique so that your server-side script gets all the data correctly

Comment: @ChrisW Save & Continue will direct the browser to another page.

Comment: So I really don't see the problem.  If the page in your image is `page1.php`, and 'Save & continue' goes to `page2.php`, `page2.php` contains the logic for uploading / getting the data from `page1.php` (all this info is in the PHP $_GET array). Do you know how to upload form data using PHP?

Comment: @ChrisW Its OK. Did you consider the 'Detail list' ? It may have number of records.

Comment: So does "Add new detail" trigger a JavaScript event or go to a different page?

Comment: ChrisW It was for JavaScript. Anyway, I could do it. I used server side program for both buttons. But the scope of the question still remains.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can store the details data in javascript but you have to put that details in the form somehow, unless you send it via Ajax, but I am not sure if you can hold the image with javascript and then send it.
I think that you can also try a html array form, if you want to add a detail then just add another input with javascript, I think it looks something like this.

```
<input name="detail[0]" type="text"></input>
<input name="detail[1]" type="text"></input>
```

you can read something more about this here: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/08/handling-array-html-form-elements-javascript-php.html.